# Packaging Density Beginner Question

Tags: homework

How do you calculate packaging density for a storage device with a large array of crossbar structures? One cell is at each cross point and the center to center distance between each cell is 10 nanometers. What would the density be in bits/cm^2? I cant seem to find a formula to calculate this or any helpful information for someone just introduced to the topic.

Comment: this may help: ... what does `bits/cm^2` mean?   what is it in words?  (same way as following example: 30 km/h in words ... thirty kilometers per hour)

Answer (score 0):

How many "10 nanometers" is there in a centimeter?

How many \$10×10^{-9}\$ meter is there in a \$10^{-2}\$ meter?

That would be \$\frac{10^{-2}}{10×10^{-9}}=10^{-2-(1-9)}= 10^6 = 1 \text{ million}\$.

So there's 1 million bits per *column*, how many *rows* are we dealing with here?

Well that would be the same in this case, so your answer is \$(1\text{ million})^2=10^6×10^6=10^{12}\$ bits.

How many bits is that in English?

One Terabit is \$10^{12}\$ bits. So you got 1 Terabit/cm². <-- Your answer

How many bytes is that?

1000/8 = 125. You got 125 Gigabytes/cm².